# How to join same department with multiple staff?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

**staff**

```
+----+- ----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| ID | fullname   | email     | countryCode | departCode | 
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 1  |  Richard   | richard@  | 1           | 1          | 
| 2  |  Tom       | tom@      | 1           | 1          |
| 3  |  Andy      | andy@     | 2           | 2          |
| 4  |  Elsa      | elsa@     | 2           | 3          |
| 5  |  Leo       | leo@      | 1           | 3          |
```

**department**

```
+------------+- ------  ----+
| departCode | departName   |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          |  Management  |
| 2          |  HR          | 
| 3          |  IT          |
```

The 1st method group_cat for my query the output:

```
select d.departName , 
GROUP_CONCAT(s.fullName SEPARATOR ' <,> ') 'fullName' ,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.email SEPARATOR ' <,> ') 'email' from staff s inner join department d on s.departCode = d.departCode 
where s.departCode and s.countryCode=2 
group by d.departCode
```

Gives the output:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| departName | fullname            | email              |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Management |  Richard <,> Tom    | richard@ <,> tom@  | 
| HR         |  Andy               | andy@              | 
| IT         |  Elsa <,> Leo       | elsa@ <,> leo@     |
```

The 2nd Method I use:

```
SELECT d.departName, s.fullName, s.position, s.site, s.ext, s.did, s.mobile, s.email from staff s 
left join department d on s.departCode = d.departCode 
left join country c on s.countryCode = c.countryCode 
where c.countryCode = 2
```

Gives the output:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| departName | fullname            | email              |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Management |  Richard            | richard@           |
| Management |  Tom                | tom@               | 
| HR         |  Andy               | andy@              | 
| IT         |  Elsa               | elsa@              |
| IT         |  Leo                | leo@               |
```

How can I use 2nd method to combine the department with multiple staff and result show multiple staff in one department?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Is a relationship between department and staff ID impossible?  This sounds like a many to many relationship that might need a second table to bridge the two relationships...

Comment: In the future, if you CREATE the table, and provide DDL to get the inserts, you'll usually get a better answer. http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/2642/2639

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to left join but then show single departments with the staff concatenated?

```
SELECT d.departName, GROUP_CONCAT(s.fullName SEPARATOR ' <,> '), GROUP_CONCAT(s.email SEPARATOR ' <,> ')
from staff s 
left join department d on s.departCode = d.departCode 
left join country c on s.countryCode = c.countryCode 
where c.countryCode = 2
group by d.departName
```